# javascript form validation doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to validate joinUs form

```
<form id="frmReg" method="post" onsubmit="return valRegs()" action="memb_area/register.php">  
//js:
function valRegs(user, pass) {
    if (!user || !pass) {
        document.getElementById('labInfo').innerHTML = "* White fields required !";
        return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["frmReg"]["mail"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        document.getElementById('labInfo').innerHTML = "Incorrect mail !";
        return false;
    }
};
```

Whichever field is filled or not, whatever is the content of mail field - the result is always: "* White fields required !". What's wrong, please?

Comment: You're not passing any argument to `valRegs()`, so `user` and `pass` will both be `undefined`, and the body of the `if` statement will always execute.

Comment: Thank you, Frederic, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you passing the parameters to the js function. try

```
function valRegs() {
        var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
         var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if (!user || !pass) {
        document.getElementById('labInfo').innerHTML = "* White fields required !";
        return false;
    }

};
```

Comment: did you try to alert the user and pass variables??

Answer (score 3):

The function will never be supplied the `user` and `pass` parameters. You will have to find these elements manually in the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`onsubmit="return valRegs()"` missed parameters